# GCloud Speech can't auth with command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-speech

I'm following [this GCloud Speech quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/quickstart) and all is well including the `"gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=[PATH]"` until I send the CURL command as below:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "$("c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\gcloud auth print-access-token") --insecure https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize  -d @c:\testing\audiotest.json
```

And I get `"Invalid Authentication Credential"`.  It seems I missed something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Are you on windows? which shell you are running this in? Add -v flag to curl to see what actual value is being set in the header for "Authorization Bearer". In particular you have a typo "Authorization: Bearer" should be "Authorization Bearer:"

Comment: @cherba there is no typo. It is "Authorization: Bearer <token>" , check here https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/quickstart

Comment: I only got a similar "Invalid Authentication Credential" when changing few characters to the actual authentication token. I am not sure that you should add the quotation marks after the $ symbol. Have you tried without that? What do you get if you only run the "gcloud auth print-access-token" command, and pasting that result inside token here: "Authorization: Bearer <token>"